# angular restangular service is not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, resources, promise, restangular, angular-services

I have a page which has ng-init = find(), after I go to other pages and do something with the db the data in the original page will change.  And then I redirect the user to the original page. And I expect to see changes in the first page.

```
$scope.find = function() {  
    Stats.query
         .then(function(stats){
              $scope.stats = stats;  
         });
};
```

where the **Stats** is a service I created with **restangular** injected.  The service looks like this:

```
angular.module('mean.stats').factory('Stats', ['Restangular', 
    function(Restangular) {
    var stats = Restangular.all('stats');
    return {
        query: stats.getList()
    }
}]);
```

It doesn't work as I expected.  But if I use the traditional $resource approach the outcome is correct.

```
angular.module('mean.stats').factory('Stats', ['$resource', 
    function($resource) {
    return $resource('stats/:statsId', {
       statsId: '@_id'
    });
}]);
```

Also later I have figured out this restangular thing is also working correctly.  I don't quite understand why is that...  Does anyone know what is happening?  Thanks.

```
angular.module('mean.stats').factory('Stats', ['Restangular', 
    function(Restangular) {
    var stats = Restangular.all('stats');
    return {
        query: function(){
            return stats.customGETLIST('');
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Do you see a call being made in the "network" console of your browser ? So you have an error message ?

Comment: No no error message. I see the put is executed correctly too.

Comment: what if you console.log the results of the call with restangular ? Btw there are missing brackets in your second code sample, which is quite confusing :-)

Comment: I console log and realized the rectangular put is successful also my db tells me the same thing. But still the redirect doesn't show the right information. I will fix the brackets later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code block, you assigned `Stat.query` to a promise returned by `getList()` instead of a function invoking `getList()`. So the request was sent to server only once when the `Stat` factory was defined. To make it work, first make `Stat.query` a function invoking `getList()`:

```
angular.module('mean.stats').factory('Stats', ['Restangular', 
    function(Restangular) {
    var stats = Restangular.all('stats');
    return {
        query: function() {
            return stats.getList();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then invoke `Stat.query` in your `$scope.find` method: (add `()` after the `query`):

```
$scope.find = function() {  
    Stats.query()
         .then(function(stats){
              $scope.stats = stats;  
         });
};
```